# Global struct for multiple source files, C

Tags: c, struct, global-variables

I've declared a global structure in supportFunctions.h:

```
...
struct historyStruct {
    char historyArray[HISTORY_DEPTH][COMMAND_LENGTH];
    int currentSize;
    int totalCommandsExecuted;
};
extern struct historyStruct history;
...
```

And I've defined `history` in `main.c`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    struct historyStruct history;
    history.currentSize = 0;
    history.totalCommandsExecuted = 0;
...
```

`historyCommand.c`, a file where I want to use `history`, includes `supportFunctions.h` but for some reason isn't detecting my global struct `history`. Whenever I try to use it I'm getting an `undefined reference` error. Is the process I described the way to create a global struct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're declaring a local variable `history` in `main()`, this hides the global variable.

Comment: `history` isn't global. It's scope is `main()`

Comment: Where should I declare it? in the header?